# Ada: package linking error

Tags: module, package, task, ada

I have a problem with my project.
The issue problem with linking a package and visibility of the tasks.

in bufor1.ads

```
package bufor1 is
    task type Bufor is
        entry Przyjmij(Wyrob: in Typ_Wyrobow; Numer: in Integer);
        entry Wydaj(Zestaw: in Typ_Zestawow; Numer: out Integer);
    end Bufor;
end bufor1;
```

in another ads file I want to call Wydaj function like that:

```
with bufor1; use bufor1;
...
bufor1.Bufor.Wydaj(Rodzaj_Zestawu, Numer_Zestawu);
```

which causes the error:

> invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call

I'm new user of ADA. Thank in advance for your time.
Greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to make calls to a `task type`, not a task object.
Either make it a task object (of an anonymous task type):

`task Bufor is`

or create a task object:

`foo : bufor1.Bufor;
...
foo.Wydaj(Rodzaj_Zestawu, Numer_Zestawu);`